# Read Gmail XOAUTH mails without marking it read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, gmail-imap

I'm trying to read email from GMail using gmail-xoauth Gem. I want to read the email and leave its unread status.

First, I tried reading just the header. Works.

```
imap = Net::IMAP.new('imap.gmail.com', 993, usessl = true, certs = nil, verify = false)
imap.authenticate('XOAUTH2', email, access_token)
imap.select('INBOX')
imap.search(["SINCE", since]).each do |message_id|

    msg = imap.fetch(message_id,'RFC822.HEADER')[0].attr['RFC822.HEADER']
    mail = Mail.read_from_string msg
    puts mail.subject
end
```

Now, I want to read the body/text of the Email without marking it read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-store) you need to use the `store` method. The documentation mentions:

**store(set, attr, flags)**

Sends a STORE command to alter data associated with messages in the mailbox, in particular their flags. The set parameter is a number or an array of numbers or a Range object. Each number is a message sequence number. attr is the name of a data item to store: ‘FLAGS’ means to replace the message’s flag list with the provided one; ‘+FLAGS’ means to add the provided flags; and ‘-FLAGS’ means to remove them. flags is a list of flags.

The return value is an array of Net::IMAP::FetchData. For example:

```
p imap.store(6..8, "+FLAGS", [:Deleted])
#=> [#<Net::IMAP::FetchData seqno=6, attr={"FLAGS"=>[:Seen, :Deleted]}>, \\
#<Net::IMAP::FetchData seqno=7, attr={"FLAGS"=>[:Seen, :Deleted]}>, \\
#<Net::IMAP::FetchData seqno=8, attr={"FLAGS"=>[:Seen, :Deleted]}>]
```

So you have to remove the `:Seen` flag

```
imap.store(message_id, "-FLAGS", [:Seen])
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Along with this, imap.fetch(message_id, "FLAGS")[0].attr["FLAGS"] lets me know the current status of read/unread.

Answer (score 3):

This maybe be very late but I will leave it here for anyone else that stumbles onto this. If, for what ever reason you want to read the email and leave the flags intake, use:

```
imap.examine('INBOX')
```

instead of:

```
imap.select('INBOX')
```

From the [Net::IMAP doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html#method-i-examine)

> Sends a EXAMINE command to select a mailbox so that messages in the mailbox can be accessed. Behaves the same as select(), except that the selected mailbox is identified as read-only.

Comment: This is the best answer